# How to select Files from react native android application and upload it to php server?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I want to upload files from my react-native based application on android and ios. I have tried several plugins but still, there are some problems regarding different NPM package. So, anybody here can help me with the problem.

I have tried several npm packages but they are beyond my expectations.

I want to select files from mobile devices and upload them to the PHP server. whether the files could be image and video.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create PHP endpoint where you can post the images.
2. You can use this to get a video/photo from the library [react-native-image-picker](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker).
3. Send via https images to the server.

Comment: It is not working on my device when I install this package I cannot debug on my real device. if you have any solution rather than this you can suggest me I will be working through it.

Comment: You need to check why is not working for you, there must be a reason.